# Border around DIVs

Tags: css, html, web, border

I've been building this website without problems in Firefox, and when I start to use chrome for cross browser testing, I've noticed a slight border around my `<div>`.

[image]

This is what it's supposed to look like without border

[image]

But notice the slight yellow border around the div when I clicked in one of the empty spaces of the div.

I've had a similar problem with the images before, whereby I added a `border:0` and it's solved, however, for this issue, I've tried `border:0`, `border:none`, `outline:0` and they all don't seem to work.

This is quite urgent and I appreciate any help from you guys.

Please do not hesitate to ask me any questions that may aid in the solving of this problem.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Just learnt that this is a chrome's focus indicator, is the conventional `border:0`, `border:none` workable for this type?

Comment: Ehm, what do you want us to say? "The error is in line 23 of your CSS"?

Comment: This seemed like a classic "Find 5 differences between these images" question. Just kiddin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  pseudo selector
Element:focus {
Outline:none; 
}

Answer (score 1):

That yellow border is the "focus" indicator. Whereas in IE it's a dotted outline, Chrome adds a yellow border like that.

I have yet to find a reliable way to get rid of it, unfortunately, but double-check you've added the border-removing styles to the right element.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even thought of the 'focus' indicator, seems that this is the right track to search around for the solution

Answer (score 0):

The style of that div should be in a single block
if that div is called in css .maindiv
let it stands alone

```
.div{
border:0px;
}
```